# Can "as ... as" clause contain noun + adjective?

Tags: as

Can an "as ... as" clause contain a noun + adjective? For example:

> There are as many things as you want

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed sentence is correct, but note that **many** is a determiner, not an adjective.

You normally use an adjective between the as ... as and a noun (or noun phrase) after it, for example

> He is as **clever** as **me**

It is possible to put both a noun and an adjective into the as ... as section like this:

> He does not have as **nice** a **car** as me.

Comment: " as nice a car" Why are you using an article after an adjective? Also, determines are considered as adjectives.

Comment: @dBio It's fine to use an adjective phrase before "a". In "As nice a car", the adjective phrase "as nice" is a predeterminer introduced by the degree modifier "as". Such AdjPs are said to be in 'external' position. And determiners are not adjectives, they are usually 'determinatives' like "a", "the", "each", "any" etc.

Comment: @dBio: check this link:  https://www.englishgrammar.org/asas/, in particular the example "He is as good a cook as his wife is! "

Comment: Is this only for the as ... as or it works in any case?